# Creating a javascript object within an iFrame by accessing the parent window

Tags: javascript, iframe-app

I know that I can access any function in a `parent window` from an `iFrame` by saying `window.parent.whateverFunctionItIs();` provided that the parent document does indeed contain a function named `whateverFunctionItIs`.
The question is, how do I create such an object within an `iFrame` like I would normally create by using something like `object1 = new ObjectMaker();` given that `ObjectMaker` exists in the parent document.

Comment: `new window.parent.ObjectMaker()`

Comment: Why do you think it would be any different?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is,

`object1 = new window.parent.ObjectMaker();`

Possible mistake for beginners,

`object1 = window.parent.new ObjectMaker(); // WRONG!`